# Kotlin Data Class: how to set a property if I don't know its name at compile time?

Tags: kotlin

So, I'm trying to set a property of a data class after compile time. I'm attempting to use bracket notation, but the IDE is barking at me with the following: `No set method providing array access`.

I did a little research, and it looks like I need to use the Reflection api. Tried using `memberProperties`, but after identifying the property there's no `setter` method on it. So, I'm here hoping to find some guidance.

Here's a contrived example of what I'm trying to do:

```
data class EmailMessageStats(
    var bounce: Int = 0,
    var click: Int = 0,
    var deferred: Int = 0,
    var delivered: Int = 0,
    var dropped: Int = 0,
    var open: Int = 0,
    var processed: Int = 0,
    var spamreport: Int = 0
)

val sampleResponseFromDatabase = listOf(
    mapOf("type" to "bounce", "value" to 148),
    mapOf("type" to "click", "value" to 142),
    mapOf("type" to "deferred", "value" to 286),
    mapOf("type" to "delivered", "value" to 700),
    mapOf("type" to "dropped", "value" to 152),
    mapOf("type" to "open", "value" to 550),
    mapOf("type" to "processed", "value" to 1000),
    mapOf("type" to "spamreport", "value" to 140)
)

var summary = EmailMessageStats()
for (row in sampleResponseFromDatabase) {
    val type = row["type"] // e.g. bounce
    val value = row["value"] //e.g. 148
    summary[type] = value
}

println(summary)
```

Comment: You should simply not use reflection. Transform your list into a Map<String, Int>, and then use `summary.bounce = map["bounce"] ?: 0`(and similarly for the other properties)

Comment: So, the example is contrived, and the `sampleResponeFromDatabase` is the result of a `@SqlQuery` which returns a `List<>` containing another data class representing the data model for the query. Not sure that I can just flip it to a `Map<>` in this case. Thanks though!

Comment: Then it's even simpler. Iterate through the list, and for ech element, use `summary.bounce = elementFromTheList.somePropertyContainingTheBounce`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made a Kotlin extension function just for that functionality:

```
fun Any.setPropertyValue(propName: String, value: Any) {
    for (prop in this::class.declaredMemberProperties) {
        if (prop.name == propName) {
            (prop as? KMutableProperty<*>)?.setter?.call(this, value)
        }
    }
}
```

Similarly for getting the property value:

```
fun Any.getPropertyValue(propName: String): Any? {
    for (prop in this::class.declaredMemberProperties) {
        if (prop.name == propName) return prop.getter.call(this)
    }
    return null
}
```

Here, you can set the property as follows:

```
var summary = EmailMessageStats()
for (row in sampleResponseFromDatabase) {
    val type = row["type"] // e.g. bounce
    val value = row["value"] //e.g. 148
    summary.setPropertyValue(type, value)
}
```

Keep in mind to use `declaredMemberProperties` if you only want the fields related to `EmailMessageStats`. Otherwise, if `EmailMessageStats` were to extend from another object, it will iterate through that object's fields too.

Comment: Thanks a ton! I knew there had to be a way to do this, but I've been banging my head on this all day. The setter was exactly what I needed. Thanks a bunch, and if I can float you a cup of coffee or something don't hesitate to ask!

Comment: I see quite a few suggestions to use reflection, but IMO it's rarely a good solution: it performs badly; it may not be available on all platforms; it defeats the type system, so you're more likely to get runtime errors; it's harder to follow the code; and you get much less help from your IDE.  It may be tempting if you're used to dynamically-typed languages, but Kotlin doesn't really work that way.  Reflection's useful for compile-time tools, plug-ins, and dependency injection frameworks; but within your own code it's a code smell, and IME usually indicates you should rethink the design.

Answer (score 0):

I got it worked in following way:

```
data class Item(var name: String, var description: String?)
```

On runtime

```
val item = "Runtime item object"
val property = "name"
val value = "Updated value of name"

val jo = JsonParser().parse( Gson().toJson(item) ).asJsonObject

if(jo.has(property)) {
    jo.remove(property)
    jo.addProperty(property, value)
}

val item = Gson().fromJson(jo, Item::class.java)
```